Vertical scrollbar not visible but working in domLayout 'autoHeight'
I was previously using ag grid v28 and now migrated to ag-grid v32.
I am using domLayout as 'autoHeight' in my gridOptions.
And in my styling I was given around 250px for .ag-body-viewport and overflow-y: auto; as given below.
.ag-body-viewport {
  height: 250px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

But after upgrading, the vertical scroll is working but the scrollbar is hidden.
Someone help
Previously the vertical scrollbar was visible with same code in v28, there is nowhere mentioned about this in their upgrade notes.
If I give scrollbar-width: thin ! important;
I am able to see the thin scrollbar, but I am expecting the old behaviour

please share a working example where the issue happens

Wherever if you use domLayout as autoHeight. For example, " https://www.ag-grid.com/examples/grid-size/auto-height/modules/typescript "    Here if you click on auto height with 50 rows. In the devTools, for .ag-body-viewport property if you add height:200px, overflow-y: auto; the scroll will work but vertical scrollbar will be hidden. This is the issue I am facing

@SudeepKS there's some CSS which is setting the scrollbar to have display: none !important and scrollbar-width: none !important

To the  viewport if I add scrollbar-width as thin, I am getting the thin scrollbar but other than thin any other properties are not working.   ag-body-viewport { scrollbar-width: thin !important }

Did you find a solution? I see the scrollbar-width: none !important
